# Application memory issue with mac

Tags: java, macos, memory, javafx

I face a problem with java application I built in javaFx. It consumes only 2-3% of cpu usage and around 50 to 80 MB of memory in windows. But in mac same application initially starts with 50 mb of memory and continuously increases to 1 GB and uses over 90% of CPU Usage. I found this information when I checked Mac task manager.  When I use a java profiler to find memory leaks, the profiler shows memory usage same like window (not more than 100 MB).

I am confused with this behaviour in Mac.

Has anyone encountered this problem before, or am I doing something wrong with my application?

Comment: Are you testing the `Windows` and `Mac` similarly? In other words, could the `Windows` app end up with 90% CPU and 1 GB RAM if you tested it in the same way as the Mac? I'm not sure if it matters, but could you post the `JRE`'s you're using?

Comment: its mac os x and using java1.7_9 version. actually this behave for all the java-fx appliation.

Comment: So you're using `java1.7_9` on both `Mac` and `Windows`? What does `actually this behave for all the java-fx application` mean?

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602557/java-issue-memory-and-cpu-usage-in-mac-os?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things possible, but i suspect this: Depending on the memory size and cpu count, the jvm may run in server mode, which causes memory management to be different. Use -server option to force it to be server mode always and compare again.

Can also take heap dumps (jmap -dump) to see what is taking up so much memory, and stack traces (kill -3) to see what is taking up so much cpu.