# Java Issue: Memory and CPU usage in MAC OS

Tags: macos, memory-management, javafx-2, java-7, cpu-usage

I am developing a javaFx application for MAC and Windows, and I found that the application is using extremely large memory and cpu usage in MAC compared to Windows.

When I see my application's activity in Windows Task Manager, it shows usage of average 80MB memory and 1-2%  CPU which reaches it maximum of 150MB and 12-15% CPU. On the other hand in MAC Activity Monitor the same application shows 150MB and 12-15% CPU at starting and increases continuously beyond 1GB and 90%CPU.

This is a very strange problem I found in my JavaFX application.

I even tested this for simple java application and found similar behavior with memory and CPU in MAC and windows.

Why Java uses more memory and CPU in MAC ? Is there any why to solve this problem ?

Comment: Which Java/JavaFX versions are the different platforms running?

Comment: Java1.7 and JavaFx2.2

Comment: If you run the mac version under a JDK you can run visualvm.  On the left you should see the java process running your application.  If you take a heap dump (huhuhuh) you can investigate what objects are using memory.  This is great practice for a very important java skill.

Comment: @AndyTill, I already tried your suggestion and VisaulVM in MAC shows me low memory and CPU usage which is near equal to VisaulVM in Winodws. But in MAC Activity Monitor it is really a strange behavior.

Comment: That is strange, does it do it with a hello world type program or is it just javafx?

Comment: @AndyTill: For both, Java and JavaFx. I think there's something wrong with garbage collection.

Comment: You may try tuning of GC http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#G1Options

Comment: You are using MAC system or Virtual System/PC of MAC?

Comment: @MarmiK, I am using MAC System (OS X 10.7.5)

Comment: @ShreyasDave also check this page from Oracle http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml this states this "Oracle's Java version 7u17 and below have been disabled by Apple on OS X. Updating to the latest release will allow Java to be run on Mac OS X. 
» Download latest Java ". I hope this will do.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have seen many problems when the Java launched new version that was not supported initially, due to security flaw(gatekeeper was blocking it/or not working)

this is the link if that help make it supporting more,

[Old Post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58203/mountain-lion-with-java-7-only)

I will say the securty feature of MAC will become bug some time as it explicitly do not update any plugin, so check the version of JAVA, and plugins if working fine.. [post](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559) as old I don't know which plugins may be required but this is main concern of problems where plugins don't work properly..

also check this, if your system are accessing JAVA 6 also which was previously there please remove to avoid the same refer [Discussion on apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58203/mountain-lion-with-java-7-only)

JAVAFX and JDK must be installed in same directory structure [Oracle MAC FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mac-faq.html) question 2

I am not regular user of MAC, as not much required,(once a while)..

But do keep track of the versions and updates. :)

I hope this will solve..

My main focus is of old java 6 is also there please remove the directories of the same..

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments. I have tried this with java1.7u09 , Java1.7u10, and Java1.7u21. They all behave same with memory managements (continuously increase in memory and does not free memory -activity monitor).

I also tried with Java8 earlier versoion, and I found that Java8 is good in memory management (Increase memory to certain level and also free memory). But there are few graphical issues in JavaFx with Java 8 and I don't want to use java8 earlier version.

Comment: I was making same point if the gate keeper is blocking the process, it may also block the process sub part, so If possible Please download latest version and try one more time.. if that may solve problem, refer faq page http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml this states previous versions not supported, and blocked.. or start the program with ctrl click as admin and then test again. if any change!!, thank you for comments..